# Exclude current document sections from sphinx toctree

Tags: python-sphinx, toctree

I have rst document like:

```
######
Title
######

.. toctree::
  :hidden:
  :titlesonly:

  subpage1
  subpage2
  subpage3

Section1
---------

Section2
---------
```

This results in toctree

```
 Title
  subpage1 title
  subpage2 title
  subpage3 title
  Section1
  Section2
```

Is there a way to remove the `Section1` and `Section2` from the toctree - I want in it, only what I explicitly stated

Comment: Section1 and Section2 are not in the `toctree` directive. When you render to HTML, the `toctree` is rendered, followed by the two section headings. If you don't want the headings, remove them.

Comment: The indentation of `.. toctree::` is wrong.

Comment: @mzjn - thx. I fixed in, I think

Answer (score -1):

It seems adding `:titlesonly:` to the parent document toctree directive achieved what I wanted.

Comment: What exactly did you change? You already have `:titlesonly:` in the question.

Comment: I added the :titlesonly: to the **parent**  document toctree

Comment: There is no "parent document" in the question. I still don't understand what the problem  is and how to reproduce it.